# The recognition of text in an arbitrary location

Tags: c#, tesseract

For text recognition, I use Tesseract - https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract there Are a few questions:

If the text is small enough compared to the image, then you can't recognize the text at all.In other words, you need to select a specific area with the text. Is there any other way to solve this problem?
In the images I process, the text is placed in an arbitrary way, i.e. you can't specify the area with the text in advance. Is there a way to solve this problem?
c#.
There is [this](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html), but again not a word about the arbitrary location of the text

Answer (score 0):

you will have to find the text positions yourself. Check out opencv findContours.